# too many 503 errors

Tags: 7

I am using cloudflare as a CDN. It started giving 520 errors lately,followed with the server going offline. I enquired to their customer support. They said that my server is giving 503 errors and thats the reason. This is what they pulled from their error log:

> 09/14 07:04:39 adda0ac581c038e www.exmple.com /favicon.ico 115.241.244.247 141.101.116.101 503 9026 www.example.com    141.101.116.101 115.241.244.247 23f8 /favicon.ico MISS 503
>
> 09/14 07:04:37 adda09fc63a038e www.example.com /article/articlename 115.241.244.247 141.101.116.101 503 9095 www.example.com   141.101.116.101 115.241.244.247 23f8 /articlename MISS 503
>
> 09/14 07:04:33 adda086e1d6038e www.example.com /favicon.ico 115.241.244.247 141.101.116.101 503 9026 www.example.com   141.101.116.101 115.241.244.247 23f8 /favicon.ico MISS 503
>
> 09/14 07:04:22 adda03f95c6038e www.example.com /articlename 115.241.244.247 141.101.116.101 503 9095 www.example.com   141.101.116.101 115.241.244.247 23f8 /articlename MISS 503

I contacted my server administrator and he said that the problem is with my script. I dont know where to start. The frequency of the error started increasing nowadays and it really annoys me as well as my customers. I noticed that this is found more if I try to enable a module, add content,flush the cache, etc. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Seems your site is slow. Like, very, very slow. I have much more complicated Drupal sites (judging by output) loading faster with apache working on my battered netbook, and it's too weak for some flash games. And HTTP 503 means "*The server is currently unavailable (**because it is overloaded** or down for maintenance)*". Have your system administrator told you what exactly is that slow? Is it PHP timeouting? Or maybe MySQL poor response times or heavy load? It's the easy path for sysadmin to say "it's programmer's fault". How are your cache settings? And your popularity?

Comment: Well, everything from system administration to site maintenance, I do it myself. I cache page for anonymous users, and block cache is enabled. Compression for cached pages is on, aggregation and compression for css and javascript is on. The site is new, and its daily page views are less than 50.

Comment: If page is that slow with less than 50 daily pageviews, and cache is on, then something is really, really wrong with your hosting. Especially given the fact that some of those overload errors happens on file requests when PHP is not even run and no database connection is created. Try running clean Drupal install there, if problem will persist (and I bet it will), you have a unfit hosting.

Comment: Changed the host, that solves it.

Answer (score 3):

503 (Service unavailable) errors are usually caused by the server being overwhelmed by requests (or beng down for maintenance). It is unlikely that a script (which runs on the client side) is going to bring a server to its knees.

Check your logs at `/admin/reports/dblog` to see if your site has had a lot of attempts by spammers to log in. It might be a Denial of Service by spam bots, in which case you should implement some anti-spam measures.

Comment: Thank you for a quick answer. domain.com/admin/reports/dblog does not exist. Also, admin folder in public_html is also empty. Can you please specify how to pull the error log? I don't suspect spam bots trying to login to site. They may be having a go at the server. How to know that? Is it possible that my drupal site(too performance heavy on the server) itself is slowing down the server(low on resources)? Thank you

Comment: Log in as an administrative user, and enter the path in your browser. It is a Drupal path, not a directory structure. If you don't know how, get some help from the site developer.

Comment: I did exactly that. www.mysite.com/admin/reports/dblog returns the same page as www.mysite.com/admin/reports and it has links named status report, available updates, etc. By the way, I developed the website myself.

Comment: That path should lead to a report menu item called 'Recent log messages'. Have a look at `/admin/config/development/logging` and see if you are keeping database log messages on your site.

Comment: You can also check the answer to this recently posted [question](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/87064/drupal-7-reports-recent-log-message) for another method.

Comment: Even more basic, and I apologize for my assumption :-) Do you have the core database logging module activated?

Comment: Sorry, I missed on it. Got it activated now. Will get back after checking the logs. thank you.

Comment: logs does not reveal any particular finding.. the problem still continues.

Comment: If it's shared hosting and the server is under dos attack the particular logs may not be of help at all. Maybe poor provider guys don't know what hit them, but still 'it's your script's fault' imho is a ridiculous unprofessional unwilling-to-help answer so changing provider is one-way to go.

Comment: I'm also getting this problem. On live-shared hosting i get 503 service unavailable and 504 gateway timeout, sometimes internal server error. One thing weird is that on my localhost (Acquia DevDesktop bundle) Im also gettng 503! Using xampp the site is too slow. Both on Windows XP and Windows 8. Server hosting blaming it on my 'script'. The site works perfectly but at times i get these. And are getting more frequent the more i configure the site. What could be happening??